# Inserir PDO MySQL

Tags: mysql, pdo

Bom, estou precisando fazer um inserção e utilizo PHP OO, porém, como devo fazer isto? Segundo o meu código está cadastrando, porém não está funcionando perfeito.

Estou fazendo algo de errado ? 
Não da nenhuma mensagem de erro, somente fala que está cadastrado com sucesso!

```
        try {
                   $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_PESSOAS (
                                       COD_IDENT_IGREJ,
                                       TXT_NOMEX_PESSO,
                                       TXT_FONEX_PESSO,
                                       DAT_NASCI_PESSO,
                                       FLG_SEXOX_PESSO,
                                       FLG_IDENT_PESSO,
                                       TXT_EMAIL_PESSO,
                                       TXT_SENHAX_USUAR,
                                       TXT_ENDER_CEPXX,
                                       TXT_ENDER_BAIRR,
                                       TXT_ENDER_LOGRA,
                                       TXT_ENDER_NUMER,
                                       TXT_ENDER_COMPL,
                                       COD_IDULT_ATUAL,
                                       DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL)
                               VALUES (:COD_IDENT_IGREJ,
                                       :TXT_NOMEX_PESSO,
                                       :TXT_FONEX_PESSO,
                                       :DAT_NASCI_PESSO,
                                       :FLG_SEXOX_PESSO,
                                       :FLG_IDENT_PESSO,
                                       :TXT_EMAIL_PESSO,
                                       :TXT_SENHAX_USUAR,
                                       :TXT_ENDER_CEPXX,
                                       :TXT_ENDER_BAIRR,
                                       :TXT_ENDER_LOGRA,
                                       :TXT_ENDER_NUMER,
                                       :TXT_ENDER_COMPL,
                                       :COD_IDULT_ATUAL,
                                       :DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL)");

        $collection = array(
            'COD_IDENT_IGREJ' => $codIgreJ,
            'TXT_NOMEX_PESSO' => $lbl_NOME,
            'TXT_FONEX_PESSO' => $lbl_TELEFONE,
            'DAT_NASCI_PESSO' => $dte_ANIVERSARIO,
            'FLG_SEXOX_PESSO' => $lbl_SEXO,
            'FLG_IDENT_PESSO' => $lbl_FLAG_IDENT,
            'TXT_EMAIL_PESSO' => $lbl_EMAIL,
            'TXT_SENHAX_USUAR' => $lbl_SENHA,
            'TXT_ENDER_CEPXX' => $lbl_CEP,
            'TXT_ENDER_BAIRR' => $lbl_BAIRRO,
            'TXT_ENDER_LOGRA' => $lbl_RUA,
            'TXT_ENDER_NUMER' => $lbl_NUMERO,
            'TXT_ENDER_COMPL' => $lbl_COMPLEMENTO,
            'COD_IDULT_ATUAL' => $lbl_COD_ID,
            'DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL' => $lbl_NOW
        );

        $sql->execute($collection);
        /* $UltAiAdd = $conn->lastInsertId();

          $sql2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_PESSOA_CELULA VALUES ( COD_IDENT_PESSO =  :COD_IDENT_PESSO, COD_IDENT_CELUL = :COD_IDENT_CELUL, FLG_IDENT_PESSO = :FLG_IDENT_PESSO, "
          . "COD_IDULT_ATUAL = :COD_IDULT_ATUAL, DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL = :DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL)");
          $sql2->bindParam(":COD_IDENT_PESSO", $UltAiAdd);
          $sql2->bindParam(":COD_IDENT_CELUL", $codCel);
          $lbl_FLAG_PE = 'M';
          $sql2->bindParam(":FLG_IDENT_PESSO", $lbl_FLAG_PE);
          $sql2->bindParam(":COD_IDULT_ATUAL", $lbl_COD_ID);
          $sql2->bindParam(":DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL", $lbl_NOW);

          $sql->execute(); */
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        error_log($exc->getMessage());
        echo "058"; //Erro no cadastro.
    }
    echo "057"; //Cadastrado com sucesso!
```

Comment: O que não está funcionando perfeito, pode nos mostrar?

Comment: Simplesmente não da nada. Não acusa erro, porem quando vou a tabela de dados ela não esta cadastrada.

Comment: em vez de usar bindParam, experimente passar tudo como array direto no execute: `$collection[] = ['COD_IDENT_PESSO", $UltAiAdd]; $sql->execute($collection);`

Comment: É que o bom bindParam vc tem que tratar o tipo do dado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27345/discussion-between-renan-rodrigues-and-ivan-ferrer).

Comment: vc precisa fazer o PDO imprir o erro ... `$sql->execute() ? print 'sucesso' : print_r($sql->errorInfo());` faça o mesmo para `$sql2`

Comment: Da uma olhada la

Comment: Não entendo de php, mas eu faria o inser assim:`"INSERT INTO tbl_NomedaTabela (campo1, campo2 VALUES (:valor1, :valor2)"`

Comment: faltou parentesse no `$sql->errorInfo()` ... eu esqueci de colocar.

Comment: @rray não está funcionando o comando.

Comment: Preciso que o erro apareça no console, como ficaria ?

Comment: Como tem dois inserts uma possibilidade do é de integridade referencial, o valor inserido(id) na segunda tabela não existe pq o primeiro insert falhou seja por uma restrição ou qualquer outro motivo.

Comment: Se esta chamando o esse insert via ajax, vc precisa pegar o retorno do ajax e dar um `console.log()` no seu javascript.

Comment: o `$sql->errorInfo()` retornou alguma mensagem?

Comment: Não teve nenhum log, continuou da mesma maneira.

Comment: Esse erro diz que existem mais colunas que valores no insert, deve ter algum placeholder que errado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você estava misturando a estrutura de UPDATE com a de inserção da **query**:

**Para insert use:**

```
INSERT INTO TABELA (campo1, campo2) VALUES (:campo1, :campo2)
```

**Para update use:**

```
UPDATE TABELA SET campo1=?, campo2=? WHERE campo_where:campo_where
```

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_PESSOAS (
                                           COD_IDENT_IGREJ,
                                           TXT_NOMEX_PESSO,
                                           TXT_FONEX_PESSO,
                                           DAT_NASCI_PESSO,
                                           FLG_SEXOX_PESSO,
                                           FLG_IDENT_PESSO,
                                           TXT_EMAIL_PESSO,
                                           TXT_SENHAX_USUAR,
                                           TXT_ENDER_CEPXX,
                                           TXT_ENDER_BAIRR,
                                           TXT_ENDER_LOGRA,
                                           TXT_ENDER_NUMER,
                                           TXT_ENDER_COMPL,
                                           COD_IDULT_ATUAL,
                                           DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL)
                                   VALUES (:COD_IDENT_IGREJ,
                                           :TXT_NOMEX_PESSO,
                                           :TXT_FONEX_PESSO,
                                           :DAT_NASCI_PESSO,
                                           :FLG_SEXOX_PESSO,
                                           :FLG_IDENT_PESSO,
                                           :TXT_EMAIL_PESSO,
                                           :TXT_SENHAX_USUAR,
                                           :TXT_ENDER_CEPXX,
                                           :TXT_ENDER_BAIRR,
                                           :TXT_ENDER_LOGRA,
                                           :TXT_ENDER_NUMER,
                                           :TXT_ENDER_COMPL,
                                           :COD_IDULT_ATUAL,
                                           :DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL)");

$collection = array(
  ':COD_IDENT_IGREJ' => $codIgreJ,
  ':TXT_NOMEX_PESSO' => $lbl_NOME,
  ':TXT_FONEX_PESSO' => $lbl_TELEFONE,
  ':DAT_NASCI_PESSO' => $dte_ANIVERSARIO,
  ':FLG_SEXOX_PESSO' => $lbl_SEXO,
  ':FLG_IDENT_PESSO' => $lbl_FLAG_IDENT,
  ':TXT_EMAIL_PESSO' => $lbl_EMAIL,
  ':TXT_SENHAX_USUAR'=> $lbl_SENHA,
  ':TXT_ENDER_CEPXX' => $lbl_CEP,
  ':TXT_ENDER_BAIRR' => $lbl_BAIRRO,
  ':TXT_ENDER_LOGRA' => $lbl_RUA,
  ':TXT_ENDER_NUMER' => $lbl_NUMERO,
  ':TXT_ENDER_COMPL' => $lbl_COMPLEMENTO,
  ':COD_IDULT_ATUAL' => $lbl_COD_ID,
  ':DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL' => $lbl_NOW
);
$conn->execute($stmt, $collection);
$UltAiAdd = $conn->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: Tentarei daqui a pouco, eu posto o resultado, obrigado por enquanto.

Comment: Acho que a forma de declarar o array abreviado foi no [5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)

Comment: [Mon Aug 24 10:55:39 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.105] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/pdo_acao.php on line 47, referer: http://127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/Users/hotsystems/AppData/Local/XDK/xdk-scratchdir/b9796bb6-a6c6-4479-94a3-7154a6043f83/platforms/android/assets/www/index.html

Comment: Deu este erro...

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta, de uma olhada la.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues, desculpe, havia um erro, veja se funciona agora. O values estava duplicado de forma errada.

Comment: [Mon Aug 24 11:37:52 2015] [error] [client 192.168.1.105] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/renan/pdo_acao.php on line 47, referer: http://127.0.0.1:58889/http-services/emulator-webserver/ripple/userapp/x/C/Users/hotsystems/AppData/Local/XDK/xdk-scratchdir/b9796bb6-a6c6-4479-94a3-7154a6043f83/platforms/android/assets/www/index.html

Comment: Mude para o `array()` tradicional. e tente novamente.

Comment: Estava faltando alguns campos, conforme @rray apontou.

Comment: Teste e veja se parou de dar erro.

Comment: Pronto, porem agora voltou o problema de não cadastrar.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27353/discussion-between-ivan-ferrer-and-renan-rodrigues).

Answer (score 1):

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in

Significa que no insert existem mais colunas especificadas do que valores, no caso você tem um bind que não está mapeado para um coluna que é `:TXT_FONEX_PESSO`

Comment: Mas o erro não é este pois eu consertei e conitnua

Comment: Continua a mesma mensgam de erro? @RenanRodrigues

Comment: sim. o erro do log é o memso

Comment: Atualizei novamente e o erro continua o que poderia ser ? Será que há alguma forma mais fácil para mim desenvolver este insert ? O interessante é que o select funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Tem um bind que está `XT_SENHAX_USUAR`, parece que faltou um `T` antes. @RenanRodrigues